# Get specific string from the text file

Tags: android, regex, string

I have a text file ,I need to get heading from the text file. Heading start from this">>".
i.e

In November 1901, present day tehsils of Mianwali, Isa Khel and Piplan were separated from Bannu District and districts Bhakkar and Layyah from Dera Ismail Khan District and clubbed together to form a new district named Mianwali with its headquarters in Mianwali city. The municipal committee was founded in December 1903 and has remained operational since then.

>>Infrastructure

The city has an FM radio station (FM 93), municipal library called Professor Muhammad Feroz Shah Library, sports complex, and hockey stadium.

>>Namal College Mianwali

In 2008, the former cricketer, philanthropist and politician Imran Khan founded the Namal College located about thirty kilometers from the Mianwali city.

I need to get the heading in separate string.

```
int firstHeading= text.indexOf("1>>");
int secondHeading= text.indexOf("2>>");
int thirdHeading= text.indexOf("3>>");
int forthHeading= text.indexOf("4>>");
int fifthHeading= text.indexOf("5>>");
int sixthHeading= text.indexOf("6>>");

headingDetail1= text.substring(firstHeading, secondHeading);
headingDetail2= text.substring(secondHeading, thirdHeading);
headingDetail3= text.substring(thirdHeading, forthHeading);
headingDetail4= text.substring(forthHeading, fifthHeading);

heading1=text.substring(firstHeading, text.indexof("?"));
```

Comment: It would help if you show what you've tried so far, otherwise looks like you're asking for code.

Comment: Not sure how to do regex in Android, but check out this regex: [`/^>>(.*)/gm`](http://regex101.com/r/qP1zP2).

Comment: I want to get the line that start from ">>".

Comment: @Sam Sullivan thanks. I think it will work

Comment: @SamSullivan why don't you upgrade your comment to an answer - at least for closure

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with regular expressions in Android, but the regex you are looking for is `/^>>(.*)/gm`.  This will do a global/multi-line match of lines starting with `>>` followed with 0+ characters (`.*`) that do not include new-lines.  Since this is in parenthesis, they will be in a match group.

You can see a better explanation here: http://regex101.com/r/qP1zP2